# Dump-based incremental backups of immutable rows MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup

I have a database where only `SELECT` AND `INSERT` privileges are granted. My idea was to do incremental dumps based on the last backed up row of the last dump (autoincrement PK). Something like `--where 'id > 100'`.

Has anyone attempted something like this? I have a couple of potential issues in mind, particularly regarding schema changes:

- The dump must generate inserts that specify the column names, otherwise restore would fail when adding new columns.
- Removing or renaming columns would break restores.

Comment: *Removing or renaming columns would break restores.* These operations are not possible when *only SELECT AND INSERT privileges are granted*.

Comment: *restore would fail when adding new columns.* You cannot take this into account. There is no DDL triggers in MySQL, so you cannot find the moment when (and by what way) the structure was changed.